# Cast given object into its class at runtime without conditionals?

Tags: c#, .net

Is it possible to cast a generic class to its specialized version without making use of the `is` operator?

I ask this because in many Repeaters the `OnItemDataBound` I have to find the current class with `is`:

```
protected GenericDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
   if(e.Item.DataItem is SpecialClass)
       ((SpecialClass)e.Item.DataItem).DoWhateverIWant();

    if (e.Item.DataItem is MoreThanSpecialClass)
       ((MoreThanSpecialClass)e.Item.DataItem).DoWhateverIWant();
}
```

I can't do the following since it won't compile for it doesn't know the type at compile type:

```
protected GenericDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
   ((e.Item.DataItem.GetType()) e.Item.DataItem).DoWhateverIWant()
}
```

I understand that this example is not perfect - and the engineering of the classes is not perfect, but it is an oversimplification of a wider case, I've seen other questions where the OP just needed to call a method and that is not the case, there are evaluations and other procedures being made inside the conditions that I would not want to repeat...

Comment: i can't see any difference between  both if statements

Comment: First of all your usage of word "generic" is confusing, because it suggests that you're thinking about generics, and apparently you're not. Secondly: why not make `DoWhateverIWant` virtual? Then you won't need the casts.

Comment: What you want can be achieved with reflection, but it is **not** a good idea. If it's not very, very important, stick to the ifs.

Comment: @Arun I've made a slight mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't you make the method really generic with a constraint that it must be a `ClasseItemServico`?

```
protected void GenericDataBound<T>(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e) where T : ClasseItemServico
{
    ((T)e.Item.DataItem).DoWhateverIWant();
}
```

I assume that both classes inherit from `ClasseItemServico`, don't they?

You would use it in this way:

```
protected void Repeater1_DataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        GenericDataBound<SpecialClass>(sender, e);  // here you know the type
    }
}
```

Comment: I've made a mistake, just updated the code to reflect the reality

Comment: @Jonathan: does that make a difference?

Comment: I'm merely stating this because there is no more ClasseItemServico in the code and the name is out of context for other readers :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, the thing is that for doing the cast, you need to tell the compiler what type you want to cast to.

The best solution would be to use proper inheritance and using a virtual `DoWhateverIWant` method.

If you are not inheriting from a base class you can use the `dynamic' keyword:

```
protected GenericDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    dynamic dObj =  e.Item.DataItem;
    dObj.DoWhateverIWant();
}
```

In this example, basically you tell the compiler: "trust me, this method exists".